# Unable to Write to Firebase database to specific node

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write some data to Firebase Database to the `isAdmobEnabled` node directly and not to create a child of it

[image]

What i am trying to achieve is the following output :

```
isAdmobEnabled : "true"
```

But my code is creating a child of it, how to avoid it? This is what i am trying :

```
adSubmitReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads").child("isAdmobEnabled");
UpdateAdsModel updateAdsModel = new UpdateAdsModel(switchStatus);
adSubmitReference.setValue(updateAdsModel).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(AdsActivity.this, "Task Completed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AdsActivity.this, "Some Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my UpdateAdsModel class :

```
public class UpdateAdsModel {

    String isAdmobEnabled;

    public UpdateAdsModel() {
    }

    public UpdateAdsModel(String isAdmobEnabled) {
        this.isAdmobEnabled = isAdmobEnabled;
    }

    public String getIsAdmobEnabled() {
        return isAdmobEnabled;
    }
}
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `adSubmitReference` variable already refers to the `isAdmobEnabled` property in the database, you should set only the value of *that* property to it.

So:

```
adSubmitReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads").child("isAdmobEnabled");
adSubmitReference.setValue(switchStatus)
```

If you already have an existing `UpdateAdsModel` object, you can also read the specific property value from that object like this:

```
adSubmitReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads").child("isAdmobEnabled");
adSubmitReference.setValue(updateAdsModel.getIsAdmobEnabled())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads").child("isAdmobEnabled").setValue(switchStatus);
```

Why? You are setting the `"isAdmobEnabled"` value to an entire object, like this in JSON:

`{"isAdmobEnabled": {"isAdmobEnabled": "true"}}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
adSubmitReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads").child("isAdmobEnabled");
```

Just Remove this Child like this

```
adSubmitReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DatabaseReference Ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads");
DatabaseReference Ref1 = zonesRef.child("IsAdmobEnabled");
DatabaseReference zone1NameRef = zone1Ref.child("IsAdmobEnabled");
```